# Instagram_basic Permission for instagram send message API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, instagram-graph-api

I have implemented a solution for sending messages through Instagram Direct using the graph API.While checking the documentation of the facebook they have given that we have to provide the **instagram_basic** permission along with **instagram_manage_messages** permission as a requirement.

[ScreenShot of the part of the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glueC.png)

[Link to the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/)

Can anybody tell the use of the **instagram_basic** permission in sending message through instagram direct.